# Embed Vimeo event iframe or api

Tags: embed, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a Vimeo event which has not played yet.

Example:  https://vimeo.com/event/4022149

Visiting the link I can see video preview screen.

When I embed this I get "Sorry This video does not exist."

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/4022149" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/4022149" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I make it show the same Video preview screen?